# Anonymous Function with variable name assigned in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function, iife

Can someone clarify me out if the following code snippet represents anonymous function or **Not**?

```
var alpha = (function(){ 

    /*
        private space
    */

    return{
        //Some Code Here ...

    }
})();
```

Is this an anonymous function? This looks like structure of anonymous function to me, but I read that anonymous function is one which has no name. Here I think alpha(variable) is the name assigned to the function, so that contradicts the concept.

I know if it would have been:

```
(function(){ 

    return{
        //Some Code Here ...

    }

})();
```

Then this would have been **Anonymous Function**(self invoking) or **IIFE**.

Also, following is a simple function but **Not** Anonymous, because beta is assigned to the function (like my example above). So, if this is not anonymous function (as beta is pointed to function & represents it), then how can my previous function (alpha pointing to function) can be anonymous? Also, self invoking is extra part. Just because a function is self invoking doesn't make it **Anonymous** I believe.

```
var beta = function(){
    //Some code 
}
```

Can someone clarify me out?

Comment: It's part of anonymous function. You get self-executing anonymous function in `(function)();`, but later assign it's value to `alpha`

Answer (score 5):

`Function` has a property called `name` and [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name) clearly says

> The value of the name property is an String that is descriptive of the
>   function. The name has no semantic significance but is **typically a
>   variable or property name** that is used to refer to the function **at its
>   point of definition in ECMAScript code**.

Also, [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-isanonymousfunctiondefinition) says

> The abstract operation IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition determines if its
>   argument is a function definition that does not bind a name.

Some samples below

```js
var alpha = function(){};
console.log(alpha.name); //returns alpha

alpha = function abc(){};
console.log(alpha.name); //returns abc

alpha = { a : function(){} };
console.log(alpha.a.name); //returns a overrides alpha

alpha = (function(){ 
    return function(){}
})();
console.log(alpha.name); //return "" since inner function doesn't have a name


alpha = (function(){ 
    return (a = function(){})
})();
console.log(alpha.name); //return a since inner function is assigned to property a



alpha = (function(){ 
    return function a (){}
})();
console.log(alpha.name); //return a 

alpha = (function(){ 
    return{
    }
})();
console.log(alpha.name); //undefined since return value is an object
```

Comment: `var alpha = function(){};` this is still anonymous function. `IsAnonymousFunctionDefinition` takes expression as its argument. In this case, the expression is `funcion(){};`. And it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

The top snippet contains an anonymous function, which is immediately called. The result of the function call (the object including `Some Code here`) is assigned to `alpha`, so not the function itself.

The beta function is also anonymous (it has no name), but it is assigned to `beta`.. You could also assign it to `gamma` (as in `gamma = beta`), but the function would still be anonymous - these are just references to it, not its name.

Maybe this will make it clearer - you can say

```
var bubu = function mimi() {
}
```

This function is not anonymous, its name is `mimi`, and it is assigned to a variable called `bubu`. But `bubu` is still not the function's name, it remains `mimi`.

Answer (score 2):

All functions in your example are anonymous. You can have an anonymous function assigned to a variable, but the function itself will still be anonymous.
You can read a bit of explanation on [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions).

Answer (score 1):

In example 1, the variable becomes a reference to the **return value** of the IIFE, whereas in example 3 it becomes a reference to the **function itself**.

You cannot call `alpha()` (unless of course the IIFE returns a new function), but you can call `beta()`.